# Python - list made in whileloop does not seem to clear

Tags: python, list

My code is as follows:

```
self.newMonsterList =[]
myKeys = []
if (len(self.myList)>0):
    for i in range(len(self.myList)-1):
        myVar = self.myList[i]
        myKeys.append(myVar[1])
        lis = game.active_entities.keys()
for k in lis:
    if (k not in myKeys):
        game.active_entities[k].destroy()
for it in self.myList:
    if (it[1] in lis):
        self.setEnt(it, game.active_entities[it[1]])
    else:
        self.newMonsterList.append(it)
self.makeEnt()
```

This code, that is the method in which it is, is called in a while loop which apparently works.
makeEnt appends an Entity with it[1] as Key to self.newMonsterList.
This works, I have tested it. Therefore, an ID which is in newMonsterList after the first full round of all this code (i.e. of the while loop which calls this code) should not be there after the second.
It is, however.
If, on the other hand, I check in makeEnt whether or not the content of newMonsterList already is a key, I get correct results.
I therefore conclude that newMonsterList is not properly emptied in which run of the while-loop.
I have been trying different versions for 2 hors now....anyone got an idea?

I am trying to write that down simpler:
a is a list of Ints

d is a dict with ints as keys

```
While True:
   b=[]
   for it in a:
      if (it not in d):
         b.append(it)
         print it
      else:
         print it
    for k in b:
          d[k] = k
```

I found out now that the monsterlist is indeed emptied at each turn, however, in the ifclause  ("if (it not in d):"), "it" is appened to the list each turn. However, "it" is also definitely in d after the first iteration, I can print it.

Comment: Please? What is your problem? I guess that we won't want to reeingineer all your code snippet which is by the way improper indented...

Comment: I do not see how I could have put that question clearer, even though that might be my fault. I have a dict and 2 lists and only those values that are in list b, but not in the dict are added to list a. the values are THEN also put in the dict, the loop restarts, so the values that where in b after the first go should not be after the second, yet they are. What did I omit?

Comment: can you make a simpler example that shows the same problem? http://sscce.org/

Comment: This seems like broken English, so it may be confusing to many users.

Comment: OP: please clarify your question...the question is not very clear and if you want a solution: ask what you want, tnx

Comment: and is there any reason for `newMonsterList` to be an instance variable?  If you don't use it anywhere else in your code, make it local (take the `self.` off).  It would also help if you showed use more contex, less fluff, and make sure you indentation is correct.

Comment: I do use it some other place unfortunately.

Comment: If I show you all the context that would mean 2 files of about 200 lines.

Comment: Every iteration you reset `b` to `[]` and you don't change `a`. Of course every print will be the same.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my simple example... it is corrected now.

Comment: I just do not see...say there is a 3 in a but not in d. Well, in the second forloop it would be written into d, would not it? So, in the second iteration of the while-loop, the if-clause should no longer applay or am I making a mistake there?

Comment: You need to improve your English if you're going to write long descriptions like this. No one can answer your question because you've articulated your ideas poorly.  On a more constructive note: If you want to empty the list, you can throw in `del the_list[:]` somewhere, which empties the list.

Comment: I already tried that. And I guess if you are native speakers you must be right, but I got 105 out of 120 in my TOEFL

Comment: And I converse with British friends easily, one of them even mistook me for an American, so I never had any clue this was so bad. If you do not want to, as this is not a language forum, I understand, but might you kindly show me my mistakes?

Comment: How can I possibly make it any clearer?

Comment: @newnewbie This boils down to "An ID in `newMonsterList` after the first execution shouldn't continue to be there after the second execution. If I check `makeEnt`, everything is correct." So could you please edit your question and try and describe just the problem you are seeing (in a different way than you already have).

Comment: but...you just did that. What other information than what you just said do you need? So yes, An ID in newMonsterList after the first execution should not continue to be there after the second execution, yet it generally is. This IS my problem.

Comment: @newnewbie How do you determine it continues to be there after the second execution? (What method do you use?)

Comment: I print the whole List (which is, in fact, just one int).

Comment: Give example data for `a` and `d` to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, your code does not actually work since it is indented improperly. I get the following exception: "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that this loop iterates over `self.myList`, but **skips the last item in the list**, right?

```
myKeys = []
if (len(self.myList)>0):
    for i in range(len(self.myList)-1):
        myVar = self.myList[i]
        myKeys.append(myVar[1])
        lis = game.active_entities.keys()
```

That seems suspicious to skip the last item.

FYI, I think the above code is equivalent to:

```
assert self.myList # Because if self.myList was empty, iterating over
                   # lis (later) would have caused an NameError.
myKeys = [value for key, value in self.myList[:-1]]
lis = game.active_entries.keys()
```

Comment: In fact I was NOT aware of that as I falsely  assumed range(x) would go from 0 to x-1, so thank you a lot. However, this did not change my problem.

Comment: I have edited my small example. Well, now I am completely puzzled: I wrote one print in the if-clause and another into the else clause - and I am ALWAYS getting both of them! I thought that should not be possible?

Comment: @newnewbie How do you know you're getting both `print` statements? It's a `while` loop.

Comment: True. I had that thought five minutes ago, so I added a print right after the if-clause. The behaviour of the whole loop makes no sense to me at all.